# RecyclerView Intent classes

Tags: android

I've looked everywhere and can't figure out how to change an intent class in a Recyclerview's `onBindViewHolder` from the main activity.

If someone knows of a post that explains how you can do this for each different recycled view to go to a different activity please comment it! If you know how to do this even better!

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  holder.crate.setImageResource(listData.get(position).getCrate());
  holder.crateName.setText(listData.get(position).getCrateName());
  holder.cratePrice.setText(listData.get(position).getCratePrice());

  holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, ***changeThisClass***.class);
       context.startActivity(intent);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: According to what, jump to different Activity.

Comment: Can you post errors if any?

Comment: 0 errors. . . Just wondering how i can go about passing a different class to the "changethisclass" class for each new recycled view to go to a new activity not just the same one over and over

Answer (score 2):

> I've looked everywhere and can't figure out how to change an intent
>   class in a Recyclerview's onBindViewHolder from the main activity.

You need to give transfer the control of your `itemClickListener` in `RecylerView` to the main activity by using a **Listener**. First, create an interface for the listener in your Adapter:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

  private YourAdapterListener mListener;

  // define the listener
  public interface YourAdapterListener {
    void onItemClickListener();
  }

  // set the listener with this
  public void setListener(YourAdapterListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
  }


  ...

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         // tell the listener about the click event.
         mListener.onItemClickListener();
       }
    });
  }
}
```

Then, you need to set the listener in the main activity:

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setListener(new YourAdapter.YourAdapterListener() {
   @Override 
   public void onItemClickListener() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourClass.class);
     startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Now you can set each class for intent for different RecyclerView by changing it inside the Activity where the RecyclerView reside.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change that class based on some rule? `Activity.class` - is an object of type `Class`.
So, you can create a separate method:

```
private Class selectClass(int param){
    if (param == 0)
        return Activity1.class;
    if (param == 1)
        return Activity2.class;
    ....
}
```

and then do:

Intent intent = new Intent(context, selectClass(...);

or you can do something like this:

```
Class clazz = null;
if (param == 0) 
    clazz = Activity1.class;
if (param == 1)
    clazz = Activity2.class;
....

if (clazz != null) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, clazz);
    ....
}
```

Comment: This might work, i'll try it out. Thanks! 
I am trying to send each recycle view to a new activity. Say the first one is Food, send it to a food page, the next is health, send it to a health page.. . etc. im trying to change the activity.class it sends the user to for each different view from the activity main. (just thought i'd expand, maybe help clarify)

Comment: Yes, that's the case.

Comment: How would you put this in the main activity though when you're calling your list and are specifying it for each recycleview? Would you do it based off an image or position?